# Grouping like strings and printing lowest number in that group

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am running a script that calculates a number between two data sets that gets saved to a csv file.

I am trying to have the script to only write the lowest number PER data set into a new file.

For example:

```
Set 1:
A
B
C
D
E

Set 2:
V
W
X
Y
Z
```

data output:

```
A,V,3
A,W,2
A,X,9
A,Y,1
A,Z,4
B,V,4
B,W,2
etc
E,Z,6
```

From here, I would like to read that file and then have only:

```
A,Y,1
B,W,2
etc
```

written to another file.

I have been toying around with regex, but I do not have very much experience using that module.

I am not looking for a complete solution, but maybe an idea where/what to search or if there is a better suited module/solution than regex.

Comment: So "A,Y,1" would be chosen because it is the lowest value among all the "A" values? Is that correct?

Comment: @joeb Correct. And ditto with the rest of the sets in the same file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `csv` and you want to make another `csv` with just the rows with the minimal values of the third column for the value of the first column?  This is not a regex problem.  Use the python `csv` module

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    d = {}
    for line in r:
        a, b, c = line
        c = int(c)
        if a not in d:
            d[a] = []
        d[a].append((a,b,c))
with open('output.csv', 'w+', newline='') as f2:
    w = csv.writer(f2)
    for a in sorted(d.keys()):
        w.writerow(min(d[a], key=lambda x: x[2]))
```